# Integrating SmartGWT in Gerrit (Maven project)

Tags: gwt, maven, smartgwt, pom.xml, gerrit

I want to add some feature to this project and I need smartgwt for all those fancy UI stuff. I modified the pom.xml to add the dependencies (smartgwt2.4 and skins).

```
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.smartgwt</groupId>
        <artifactId>smartgwt</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.smartgwt</groupId>
        <artifactId>smartgwt-skins</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

And inherits smartgwt to my project.gwt.xml ... So far so good, I add the new ui and implemented my stuff. Works geat on hosted mode/debug, etc...

But when I do a mvn clean install, my build is a great success. But when I try to load the daemon and check my application locally I get stuck on the hosted.html... So basically, I get stuck on the loading page..

I was wondering if that as to do with conflicting package between smartgwt and the current gwt in the project. Anyone has worked with gerrit or any similar application before that could help me out. And the great thing about this, I have no error to display...

Comment: If I check in my .m2/repo smartgwt is there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not about your smartgwt dependency. I think there are missing files which are stopping your module from loading. It used to happen to me. I would advise you to add some `SC.say("I'm here")` at the start of your entry point to see if it is reaching this far. Also, check the server logs for any errors.

**EDIT :** 
I would have to guess that the problem is in your empty **web.xml**. You should at least define a **servlet-mapping**

Comment: I checked the javascript. ANd I get an error like this:c: function koc(){var b;!! 
$stats&&Yoc('com.google.gwt.user.client.UserAgentAsserter');b=utc();n 
$c(fed,b)||($wnd.alert('ERROR: Possible problem with your *.gwt.xml 
module file.\nThe compile time user.agent value (safari) does not 
match the runtime user.agent value ('+b+'). Expect more errors. 
\n'),undefined);!! 
$stats&&Yoc('com.smartgwt.client.SmartGwtEntryPoint');oOc();!! 
$stats&&Yoc('com.google.gerrit.client.Gerrit');Lf(Kf())}

Comment: for the message you are getting, check this link: https://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/forum/#!category-topic/orkut/profile-and-friends/tiO0pMFt9b8

Comment: But I added the dependency correctly and added the smartgwt inherits to the gwt.xml...

Comment: did you add the dependencies of gwt-servlet and gwt-user? You are forgetting something but I don't seem to remember how i resolved this problem when I faced it :(

Comment: Can you please post the code of the following files: ***.gwt.xml**, **web.xml** and **WelcomePage.html**

Comment: can't see it! Write me an email.. mine is public I think.

Comment: my email is sta191919@gmail.com

Comment: But I don't know why I should change my web.xml . Before I was just using gwt and it was working. No? Plus, its a maven project... so maybe, those module are defined somewhere else.

Comment: In debug mode, the web.xml is not read. It is read in production mode. I read this somewhere